# How to match a string that is not belong to a set of substring in regex?

Tags: regex

For example:

I have a string which is:

```
k0 + k1 * x + k2 * x ** 2 + a + b + 3
```

I want to throw `k\d`, `a`, `b` away and get a list returned.

The return values should be:

```
[' + ", ' * x + ', ' * x ** 2 +', '+' + 3']
```

I tried `[^k\d+,a,b]+`

but this one cannot combine k and one or more number together, in fact, it deleted all numbers and `+` from the result.

is there any way to solve this problem?

Simple python code for testing:

```
import re

# this regex is the wrong one
str_format = re.compile(r'[^k\d+,a,b]+')
str = 'k0 + k1 * x + k2 * x ** 2 + b + a +3'
re.findall(str_format, str)
```

Comment: Maybe  `list(filter(None, re.split(r'k\d+|[ab]', text)))`?

Comment: To match any lowercase ASCII letters, use `[a-z]` instead of `[ab]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character class is used to match a single character, not a group of characters. In your case, you can achieve the result by splitting with the pattern like

```
k\d+|[ab]
```

that matches `k` and any 1+ digits after it (as a *sequence* of chars) or `a` or `b`. Then, you may remove all empty matches and get the final result:

```
import re
text = 'k0 + k1 * x + k2 * x ** 2 + b + a +3'
print (list(filter(None, re.split(r'k\d+|[ab]', text))))
```

See the [online Python demo](https://rextester.com/JAQA40032)